# convert WriteableImage to BufferedImage

Tags: java

I need some help concerning Writable- and `BufferedImages` in Java (11, Javafx):

How do I convert a `WritabeImage` to a `BufferedImage`? - WITHOUT using `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage()`

It is important for me to find a solution without `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage()`. I have already asked google, but the only results I am getting contain `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage()`. So I am asking for your expertise.

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t use SwingFXUtils?  Is that a requirement of an assignment?

Comment: I am using a JDK which does not support "jdk.unsupported.desktop" which is requiered by SwingFXUtils. And there really is no possibility to change the JDK. That's why I need a different solution.

Comment: Try to read about PixelWriter/PixelReader - this could help I suppose. Watch this for instanse: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/11/convert-bufferedimage-to-javafx-image/

Comment: I already know that articel. But it shows the way from bufferedImage to WriteableImage - and I need the opposite direction. I've tried to do it the opposite way with that code, but I am unable to do that.

Comment: How did you produce your WritableImage? Did you use PixelReader as a constructor parameter or you have some source image? If it's true, just use them to create a BufferedImage. Otherwise there's no way to READ from WRITABLE image (as far as I concerned of course)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

That is how my code looks like (including the 'SwingFXUtils' which I need to avoid):

```
static public void createImg(Node NODE, String name) {
        WritableImage SNAPSHOT = NODE.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        File file = new File(Properties.getSettingsPath() + File.separator + name + ".png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(SNAPSHOT, null), "png", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question.  If you wish to provide additional information in your question, use the “edit” link directly beneath your question’s text and add the new information to your question, rather than creating an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the pixels yourself:

```
BufferedImage convert(Image fxImage) {
    int width = (int) Math.ceil(fxImage.getWidth());
    int height = (int) Math.ceil(fxImage.getHeight());

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    int[] buffer = new int[width];

    PixelReader reader = fxImage.getPixelReader();
    WritablePixelFormat<IntBuffer> format =
        PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        reader.getPixels(0, y, width, 1, format, buffer, 0, width);
        image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, y, width, 1, buffer);
    }

    return image;
}
```